# Detecting tab view change Xcode OSX AppleScriptObjC

Tags: xcode, macos, events, applescript, applescript-objc

I am building an application in AppleScriptObjC and I have a beginner question - how can I handle clicking on tab buttons in my app? I'm trying to make it have different sizes for each tab. I can make the window resize, but not when you click on a tab. Anyway, I've connected the tab view to the delegate
[image]

and such, and added a `didSelectTabView` function as follows:

```
on didSelectTabViewItem_(tabItem)
    display alert "Testing"
end didSelectTabViewItem_
```

...and I get the following error:

```
2013-05-30 18:50:10.970 MacUtil[16354:303] Error setting value for key path self of object <AppDelegate @0x1005d3040: OSAID(4)> (from bound object <NSTabView: 0x101c05490>): [<AppDelegate 0x1005d3040> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key self.
2013-05-30 18:50:10.972 MacUtil[16354:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff911210a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9522e3f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91120ee8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff92e3414c -[NSBinder _setValue:forKeyPath:ofObject:mode:validateImmediately:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:error:] + 902
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff92e33d6d -[NSBinder setValue:forBinding:error:] + 248
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff93493625 -[NSViewStateBinder _setValue:forBinding:errorFallbackMessage:] + 63
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff933a5198 -[NSTabViewBinder tabView:didSelectTabViewItem:] + 330
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff934b9c75 -[_NSBindingAdaptor tabView:didSelectTabViewItem:] + 136
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff92fe9029 -[NSTabView selectTabViewItem:] + 1172
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff9303ea8c -[NSTabView mouseDown:] + 156
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff92fad60e -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6853
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff92fa9744 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5761
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff92ebf2fa -[NSApplication run] + 636
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff92e63cb6 NSApplicationMain + 869
    14  MacUtil                             0x0000000100000f0a main + 74
    15  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff93a297e1 start + 0
    16  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I just had to uncheck "Raises for Non Applicable Keys" in the place where you bind it to the app delegate. It was doing that because I hadn't implemented all of the methods for tab view event handling.